# How does Kotlin’s incremental compilation work?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Say I have two modules:

- `library`

  - `Library.kt`
  - `UnusedLibrary.kt`
- `app` (depends on `library`)

  - `AppWithLibrary.kt` (imports `Library`)
  - `AppWithoutLibrary.kt`

If I modify `Library.kt`, which files are recompiled?

From [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#incremental-compilation):

> Incremental compilation tracks changes of source files between builds so only files affected by these changes would be compiled.

I’d assume that only `Library.kt` and `AppWithLibrary.kt` are recompiled, but I can’t prove it with the logs. I *can* tell that both `library` and `app` modules are rebuilt, as you’d expect, but I don’t know if that means all the source files are recompiled or if just the affected ones are.